# How to pipe a string to process' STDIN?

Tags: pipe, raku

I have a command that expects input from a pipe. For example, consider the famous `cat` command:

```
$ echo Hello | cat
Hello
```

Suppose I have a string in a Perl 6 program that I want to pipe to the command:

```
use v6;

my $input = 'Hello'; # This is the string I want to pipe to the command.
my $proc  = run 'cat', :in($input);
```

This does not work (I get no output). I can work around the problem by
invoking `bash` and `echo`:

```
my $proc  = run 'bash', '-c', "echo $input | cat";
```

But is there a way I can do this without running `bash` and `echo`?

In Perl5, I could simply do `my $pid = open my $fh, '|-', 'cat';` and then `print $fh $str`.

Comment: You're actually asking how to write directly to a process' stdin. (piping is a feature of a shell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Piping several commands is easy too. To achieve the equivalent of the pipe echo "Hello, world" | cat -n in Perl 6, and capture the output from the second command, you can do*

```
my $p1 = run 'echo', 'Hello, world', :out;
my $p2 = run 'cat', '-n', :in($p1.out), :out;
say $p2.out.get;
```

*You can also feed the :in pipe directly from your program, by setting it to True, which will make the pipe available via .in method on the Proc:*

```
my $p = run "cat", "-n", :in, :out;
$p.in.say: "Hello,\nworld!";
$p.in.close;
say $p.out.slurp: :close;
# OUTPUT: «1  Hello,␤ 
#          2  world!␤»
```

Straight from the [docs](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc), btw

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know, but what if I do not want to run `echo`?

Comment: Dude, that's described in the same docs, just one paragraph later.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Are any of [these modules](http://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=capture) or  [this one](http://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=io%3A%3Astring) or [this one](http://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=string%3A%3Astream) relevant to what you want, perhaps in combination with this answer?