# If I reassigned OUT in Perl 6, how can I change it back to stdout?

Tags: raku

A very simple question, but I can't easily find an answer.

I want all `say` in a block to go to a file. But then I want my output to return to `STDOUT`. How to do that?

```perl6
my $fh_foo = open "foo.txt", :w;
$*OUT = $fh_foo;
say "Hello, foo! Printing to foo.txt";

$*OUT = ????;
say "This should be printed on the screen";
```

Comment: Edited to clarify -- as the title should not just describe the topic or subject you're asking about, but describe the *actual question itself*.

Comment: How would you do it if it weren't $*OUT but some other variable you want to temporarily overwrite?

Comment: Maybe glancing at the code in one of the modules I linked to in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271120/how-to-pipe-a-string-to-process-stdin#comment81525467_47271351) will be helpful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's much better, thanks! Holli, nice solution. raiph thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is to only change it lexically

```perl6
my $fh-foo = open "foo.txt", :w;
{
  my $*OUT = $fh-foo;
  say "Hello, foo! Printing to foo.txt";
}

say "This should be printed on the screen";
```

```perl6
my $fh-foo = open "foo.txt", :w;

with $fh-foo -> $*OUT {
  say "Hello, foo! Printing to foo.txt";
}

say "This should be printed on the screen";
```

---

If you have to work around someone else's code you could reopen it the same way it was opened in the first place.

```perl6
my $fh-foo = open "foo.txt", :w;
$*OUT = $fh-foo;
say "Hello, foo! Printing to foo.txt";

$*OUT = IO::Handle.new( path => IO::Special.new('<STDOUT>') ).open();

say "This should be printed on the screen";
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second example use `given` instead of `with`? Because if the block will contain real code, it should error out (pun not intended) rather than be silently skipped.

Comment: @Holli Brad's early examples are automatically safe. They reset the old `$*OUT` after the scope, even if the code throws exceptions. That's generally a very good habit. You can't screw it up (for example, if a coworker adds an early `return` to a function).

Comment: @piojo I was thinking about having it as `with $fh-foo {…} else -> $failure {…}`