# Capturing a module output

Tags: io, raku

Say we have this module:

```
unit module outputs;

say "Loaded";
```

And we load it like this

```
use v6;

use lib ".";

require "outputs.pm6";
```

That will print "Loaded" when it's `require`d. Say we want to capture the standard output of that loaded module. We can do that if [it's an external process](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc), but there does not seem to be a way for redirecting [`*OUT`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2AIN) to a string or,if that's not possible, to a file. Is that so?

Comment: Can re-assigning $*OUT/$*ERR dynamic variables help?

Comment: @takao can we redirect them to a string? I've seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407331/how-to-open-a-file-handle-on-a-string-in-perl-6 but I don't really understand that...

Comment: See also [If I reassigned OUT in Perl 6, how can I change it back to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47318139/2173773)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try use [`IO::String`](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-io-string):

```
use v6;
use lib ".";
use IO::String;

my $buffer = IO::String.new;
with $buffer -> $*OUT {
    require "outputs.pm6";
};

say "Finished";
print ~$buffer;
```

**Output**:

```
Finished
Loaded
```

See also [If I reassigned OUT in Perl 6, how can I change it back to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47318139/2173773)

Answer (score 7):

Temporarily reassigning `$*OUT` so that `.print` calls append to a string:

```
my $capture-stdout;

{ 
  my $*OUT = $*OUT but
             role { method print (*@args) { $capture-stdout ~= @args } }

  require "outputs.pm6" # `say` goes via above `print` method 
}

say $capture-stdout; # Loaded
```