# Raku: Sending a string to a subprocess's standard input

Tags: raku

I'd like to send a string to a subprocess's standard input stream, as I might do in Perl 5 like this:

```
pipe *READ, *WRITE;

if (my $pid = fork()) {
    close READ;
    print WRITE "Hello world!\n";
    close WRITE;
} else {
    close WRITE;
    open STDIN, '<&=' . fileno READ;
    close READ;
    exec 'cat';
}
```

What's the equivalent construction in Raku?

I can send any input to a an external `cat` process to get it back in a stream I can pass to yet another process, but that's just terrible.

I've found [this](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-io-string/) Raku module that seems relevant, but it has "Input as well as output" as a TODO, so it doesn't help me now.

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271120/how-to-pipe-a-string-to-process-stdin) on this very site that matches this one closely.  That author asked for a solution that doesn't rely on an external process, as I am, but the accepted solution still uses an external process.

Finally, I note the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Pipe) for Raku's `IO::Pipe` class, which seems like it should fit the bill.  However, that page says:

```
Pipes can be easily constructed with sub run and Proc::Async.new.
```

...which I explicitly want to avoid.  I tried just creating a new `IO::Pipe` object, hoping I could use its `in` and `out` streams in a natural way, but I get:

```
> my $pipe = IO::Pipe.new
Required named parameter 'on-close' not passed
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

That parameter is not mentioned on the doc page, so I suppose I've ventured into undefined territory here.

Comment: I'm confused because you give an example that spawns a process using fork, and then later suggest via "That author asked for a solution that doesn't rely on an external process, as I am, but the accepted solution still uses an external process." that a) you want to do it without an external process or b) the solution linked isn't sufficient despite spawning a process.

Comment: @ugexe I have a single external process I want to send data to.  What I don't want is to have to spawn a SECOND external process, a trivial one like `cat` or `echo`, just to be able to do so.

Comment: `fork` spawns a SECOND external process. In this case it is a trivial one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this turned out to be embarrassingly easy.  Just provide a boolean `True` value for `run`'s `in` parameter, then access the resulting process's `in` field and write to it.

```
my $proc = run 'my-command', 'and', 'args', :in;
$proc.in.say('Hello world!');
$proc.in.close;
```

Comment: That was in the original answer you linked btw

Comment: [The usual original meaning of raku](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+meaning+of+raku) doesn't include "embarrassing"! :)

Comment: @raiph Yes, I found the other question's answer confusing, since the question explicitly specifies not using `echo` and then the answer begins with a solution that does exactly that.  I see now that the answer actually is there.  I'm ambivalent about marking this question as a duplicate, since my question shows a wider research effort that some may find useful.